# Where is weight (in jetpack compose)?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Updated to Jetpack Compose a-08 today and have a problem. In previous builds I used weight modifier, but now i can't find it. What happened or what is the alternative? In changelogs I founded no information about it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can still find it there, but the weight modifier is a extension function inside `RowScope` and inside `ColumnScope`, which means you can only use it inside a `Column` or a `Row`.

Reference to RowScope: https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/layout/RowScope#weight

Reference to ColumnScope: https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/layout/ColumnScope#weight

Comment: I ran into a similar issue while following the jetpack compose codelab today. To say the answer in another way, I am unable to use Modifier.weight() on a Column that's not a child of another column/row. Moving the column inside another column fixed it.

Comment: See this answer for a better solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66599124/310783

Comment: I ran into similar problem. Another answer to use `weight` in a custom view https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71664252/how-to-use-row-weight-modifier-in-a-custom-view