# How can I make a composable function with `weight` modifier?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

When I have

```
Column {
    Button(onClick = { /*TODO*/ },) {
        Text("Original Window")
    }
    Button(onClick = { /*TODO*/ }) {
        Text("Fit System Window")
    }
}
```

I can create a common composable function

```
@Composable
fun MyButton(
    onClick: () -> Unit,
    content: @Composable RowScope.() -> Unit
) {
    Button(
        onClick = onClick,
        content = content
    )
}

Column {
    MyButton(onClick = { /*TODO*/ },) {
        Text("Original Window")
    }
    MyButton(onClick = { /*TODO*/ }) {
        Text("Fit System Window")
    }
}
```

However when I have

```
Column {
    Button(onClick = { /*TODO*/ },
        modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)) {
        Text("Original Window")
    }
    Button(onClick = { /*TODO*/ },
        modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)) {
        Text("Fit System Window")
    }
}
```

I cannot create below

```
@Composable
fun MyButton(
    onClick: () -> Unit,
    content: @Composable RowScope.() -> Unit
) {
    Button(
        onClick = onClick,
        modifier = Modifier.weight(1f),
        content = content
    )
}

Column {
    MyButton(onClick = { /*TODO*/ },) {
        Text("Original Window")
    }
    MyButton(onClick = { /*TODO*/ }) {
        Text("Fit System Window")
    }
}
```

This is because `weight` modifier is under `ColumnScope` interface.

How can I make a composable function with `weight` modifier?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Looks like I just need to just create an extension from of `ColumnScope`

```
@Composable
fun ColumnScope.MyButton(
    onClick: () -> Unit,
    content: @Composable RowScope.() -> Unit
) {
    Button(
        onClick = onClick,
        modifier = Modifier.weight(1f),
        content = content
    )
}
```